# prove that a function is continuous if the denominator is a continuous function

Tags: calculus, limits

Given that $f(x)$ is a continuous function and its value is positive at point $x_0$ I need to prove that:
$$
f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)} 
$$
is continuous at $x_0$. I think this is really easy but not 100% sure. My thinking is:
1) because $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists (definition of a continuous function at a given point).

2) Let's see if $lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$ exists:  $lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)} = lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{(f(x))^2 +1}{f(x)}$, provided that $f(x) \neq 0$ which is given hence the limit exists.

3) According to arithmetic of continuous functions $\frac{(f(x))^2 +1}{f(x)}$ is valid because the denominator will never be $0$. Thus the $\frac{(f(x))^2 +1}{f(x)}$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we introduce g, such as $g(x)=f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$, which is the sum of two functions .

We know that f is continuous at $x_0$ and non-null ( I guess), therefore, the inverse of this function is also continuous at that point.

The sum of two continuous functions at one point, is continuous, therefore g is continuous at $x_0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \left(f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)+\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{1}{f(x)}$$
But $f(x)$ is continuos, so 
$$\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$$ 
and $f(x_0)$ is no null (positive) so 
$$\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)}=\frac{1}{f(x_0)}$$
and then 
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \left(f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=f(x_0)+\frac{1}{f(x_0)}$$
what give us that $f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is continuos.